# Split section of video with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to get this to work and I'm really close, but something still isn't right.

I have a 14 second clip I'm trying to cut out of a longer mp4 video. I got the video to cut to the right place with this command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:13.0 -i ~/videos/trim_me.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec copy -t 00:00:14.0 ~/videos/trimmed.mp4
```

If I didn't specify `-vcodec` it was starting from an "I-Frame" (I guess) and wasn't the right place. The audio is starting from that spot as well, so I tried setting `-acodec` the same way:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:13.0 -i ~/videos/trim_me.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 225k -ar 48000 -strict -2 -t 00:00:14.0 ~/videos/trimmed.mp4
```

Which doesn't really help much. Setting `-async 1` makes it take longer, and then the audio does match up, but not until 4 seconds into the video. :/

I'd ideally not like to install anything else and have a commandline solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h264` should work as a codec, but usually defaults to `libx264`. `vcodec` ideally should be replaced with the non-deprecated `c:v`.

The working command was

```
ffmpeg -i ~/videos/trim_me.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 255k -ar 48000 \
-async 1 -strict -2 -y \
-ss 00:05:13.0 -t 00:00:14.0 ~/videos/trimmed.mp4
```

Moving the `-ss` flag as an output flag will ensure that the complete video is transcoded but output only starts at the point specified by `-ss`. Otherwise, when `-ss` is placed in front of `-i`, FFmpeg would just seek to the starting point, which might be inaccurate.

Fixing the `-vcodec` flag, and putting in `-async 1` worked, but only if done together.

Comment: I took the liberty of explaining why it probably didn't work and why the placement of option matters. Note that the `async 1` option is deprecated as well and the [`asyncts`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#asyncts) option should be used instead. `vcodec` is also deprecated. In the future, when asking questions about FFmpeg, please include the full, uncut console output as well. This will help us debug your issue.